# add a devextreme theme to an angular project in the angular way

Tags: devextreme, devextreme-angular

how to add a minimun set of styles in order to install a theme in the `angular-cli.json`?

i haven't fount anything about this way, the only example that i found is adding styles in the index.html

where are located these files in the bundle than i've installed?

```
"../node_modules/devextreme/.........."
"../node_modules/devextreme-angular/.........."
```

i can't find these files

*****RESOLVED*****
here  the example:
https://github.com/DevExpress/devextreme-angular/blob/master/docs/using-angular-cli.md

Comment: There is a github example for devextreme and Angular . Please go through it. [Devextreme-Angular](https://github.com/DevExpress/devextreme-angular) Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All themes located in `devextreme/dist/css`
There is an [example](https://github.com/DevExpress/devextreme-examples/tree/17_2/intl-angular) based on angular-cli, so you can use it as a start point.